# Sumar Filas por valor de una columna conservando el resto- Rstudio

Tags: r, rowsums

Escribo porque estoy con la siguiente duda.

Tengo un dataframe que tiene 6 columnas y 10 filas.  Tengo 4 variables (ID, PAIS, SUCURSAL, VENDEDOR) que son categoricas  y 2 que son numericas ( VENTAS Y VENTAS MES ANTERIOR). Adjunto el ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesitaria es sumar las filas de las columnas 5 y 6 (VENTAS Y VENTAS ANTERIORES) para los cuales el ID es el mismo, luego el mismo PAIS, SUCURSAL Y NOMBRE. De esta manera me quedarian menos filas que en el caso anterior, y las que se repiten aparecen tan solo una vez.  El resultado seria algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente hacerlo con la función agregate(xx, by=list) pero no me devuelve el total de columnas, sino solo las que elijo sumar y la variable especifica por la que elijo sumar. Esto es, si no elijo agrupar por todas las columnas del data frame, solo me devuelve aquellas columnas que elegi para que sume y la columna de criterio.
Tambien intente utilizar Group_by complementado con mutate, pero me agrega mas columnas al dataframe, lo que no me hace consistente los datos.

Que podria hacer? Desde ya agradezco por adelantado!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con un group_by por todas esas variables, bastaría:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID, Pais, Sucursal, Vendedor) %>%
  summarise(
    Suma_de_ventas = sum(Ventas),
    Suma_de_ventas_mes_anterior = sum(`ventas mes anterior`)
  )
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta! Intente lo que me dijiste, pero lo que ocurre es que me devuelve un DF igual al anterior, con la misma cantidad de filas, solo que cambia el nombre de las columnas por "suma de ....". No me sumo los casos que se repetian. Que puede ser?

Comment: El código esta bien, el posible problema puede estar en tu data frame, yo creo que no te esta agrupando las variables, porque las variables categoricas (pais y vendedor) no son idénticas para cada valor por el cual agrupas, con esto me refiero a que puedes tener, por ejemplo en la variable pais, "Arg" y "Arg " con espacios al final o al principio de la cadena, te recomiendo revisarlas usando
unique(df$Pais) y unique(df$Vendedor)

Comment: Efectivamente es eso! Muchas garcias!